# Deploying to Heroku with client and api in seperate folders. Failing on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am developing a NodeJS app that uses React on the front end. My folder structure is:

```
root -
  - client (React App)
  - api (express server)
```

My git folder is in the root folder for pushing the entire project to GitHub throughout development. But does my repo need to now be initialized in the api folder? Or is there a way to tell Heroku that the application is in the api folder?

Error on Heroku:

```
Build failed
There was an issue building your app. Please ensure your app is deployable to Heroku and try again.

 !     No default language could be detected for this app.
            HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically.
            See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
 !     Push failed
```

Also I feel it's worth mentioning that I set up the auto deploys in the Heroku GUI. So, it is attempting to build. I also have a Proc file and an app.json file.

app.json

```
{
    "name": "Craig Bauer | Portfolio",
    "description": "My web portfolio built as a MEAN stacjk app",
    "repository": "https://github.com/craigbauerwebdev/Portfolio",
    "logo": "",
    "keywoeds": ["node", "react", "portfolio"],
    "image": "heroku/nodejs"
},
{
    "buildpacks": [
        {
            "url": "https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-node.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Procfile

```
web: node app.js
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution and just wanted to share.
My entire production application is now in the api folder. This command worked well for me.

```
git subtree push --prefix api heroku master
```

For future projects I will structure this differently so I won't have to copy the build before each deploy.